# Defining multiple custom attributes on a custom HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, web-component, custom-tags

Adding a getter/setter for a custom attribute on a custom HTML element is fairly straightforward:

```js
  customElements.define('custom-el', class extends HTMLElement {
    
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['customAttr']
    }

    get customAttr() {
      return this.getAttribute('customAttr')
    }

    set customAttr(value) {
      this.setAttribute('customAttr', value)
    }

    constructor() {
      super();
    }
    
  })
```

However, this gets really cumbersome if you have multiple custom attributes on the same element:

```js
  customElements.define('custom-el', class extends HTMLElement {
    
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['customAttr1', 'customAttr2', 'customAttr3']
    }

    // for attr 1

    get customAttr1() {
      return this.getAttribute('customAttr1')
    }

    set customAttr1(value) {
      this.setAttribute('customAttr1', value)
    }

    // for attr 2

    get customAttr2() {
      return this.getAttribute('customAttr2')
    }

    set customAttr2(value) {
      this.setAttribute('customAttr2', value)
    }

    // for attr 3

    get customAttr3() {
      return this.getAttribute('customAttr3')
    }

    set customAttr3(value) {
      this.setAttribute('customAttr3', value)
    }

    constructor() {
      super();
    }
    
  })
```

I've been thinking of ways one could write a function that would generate getter/setters from an array of custom attribute names, but that doesn't seem possible without being able to pass a variable string as the name of the get/set.

The [documentation for "getter"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) suggests that expressions in square brackets are acceptable, and this works with one variable string:

```js
const x = "customAttr";

customElements.define('custom-el', class extends HTMLElement {
    
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return x;
  }

  get [x]() {
    return this.getAttribute(x)
  }

  set [x](value) {
    this.setAttribute(x, value)
  }

  constructor() {
    super(); 
  }

})
```

```html
<custom-el customAttr="It works"></custom-el>
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("custom-el").customAttr) // yields "It works"
```

Unfortunately, for/forEach loops are not permissible in the body of a custom element definition (outside of an embedded subroutine, at which point the get/set operations no longer work!):

```js
const customAttrs = ["customAttr1", "customAttr2", "customAttr3"];

customElements.define('custom-el', class extends HTMLElement {
    
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return customAttrs;
  }

  customAttrs.forEach( customAttr => {
    get [customAttr]() {
      return this.getAttribute(customAttr)
    }

    set [customAttr](value) {
      this.setAttribute(customAttr, value)
    }
  })

  constructor() {
    super(); 
  }

})
```

```
<custom-el customAttr1="It " customAttr2="doesn't " customAttr3="work"></custom-el>
```

```js
let customEl = document.querySelector("custom-el");
console.log(testEl.customAttr1+testEl.customAttr2+testEl.customAttr3) // yields error
```

If the custom HTMLElement class had a "defineAttribute" method which operated like an Object's "defineProperty", you could do something like:

```js
const customEl = ...

const customAttrs = ["customAttr1", "customAttr2", "customAttr3", ...]

customAttrs.forEach( customAttr => {
  HTMLElement.defineAttribute(customEl, customAttr, {
    get : function(){ return this.getAttribute(customAttr ); },
    set : function(newValue){ this.setAttribute(customAttr, newValue); }
  }
}
```

... but nothing like this seems to exist.

tl;dr - Is there really no better way to set up multiple setter/getters for custom attributes on custom elements than just writing set/get definitions out for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Object.defineProperty( element , attrName , { getter , setter , options} )`

Add ***something like*** this to your BaseClass (so `this` is your Custom Element)

```
  defineProperty(
    attr,
    getter = (attr) => this.getAttribute(attr),
    setter = (val, attr) => (val == undefined ? this.removeAttribute(attr) : this.setAttribute(attr, val)),
    options = {
      configurable: true,
    }
  ) {
    return Object.defineProperty(this, attr, {
      get() {
        return getter(attr);
      },
      set(val) {
        return setter(val, attr);
      },
      ...options,
    });
  }
```

**See:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

**Plural:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am familiar with Object.defineProperty/Object.defineProperties as they're used on objects, but I'm not quite sure I understand how you mean to implement it here. Should this be prefixed by "Object."? Do you mean that I should be defining a new function also named "defineProperty"?

Comment: Doesn't matter what you name it; this is the **method** on a (BaseClass) Element, so usage would be : ``this.defineProperty`` where  you wanted ``HTMLElement.defineAttribute``

Comment: Okay, I think I've figured out what you meant. I am not very used to default parameters yet, so I think that was what was confusing me. Nogmaals bedankt voor je hulp!

Comment: Yep, standaard parameters zijn zeer krachtig.. JavaScript is cool